# how to extract only numbers from variable and I need to give spaces between those numbers?

Tags: linux

This is the sample string variable:

```
str="A=30|B='(if a=45 then b=100 else b=101)'|C=1000"
```

Required output is:

> 30 45 100 101 1000

I had tried below regex but I did not get proper output:

```
v=$(echo "$str" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'|wc -w)
```

Let me know proper statement for getting above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the number of numbers in the string.

With GNU awk:

```
gawk '{print NF}' FPAT='[[:digit:]]+' <<< "${str}"
```

With GNU grep and wc:

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <<< "${str}" | wc -w
```

Or with `sed` and `wc (works on all platforms):

```
sed -E 's/[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+)/\1 /g' <<< "${str}" | wc -w
```

or (simpler):

```
sed -E 's/[^0-9]+/ /g' <<< "${str}" | wc -c
```

Comment: I got it but I need some explanation about gawk statement.

Comment: @RamuThuniki `FPAT` is a `gawk` extension. It means *field pattern*. You can use it to describe how a field looks like, rather than specifying the delimiter between fields. In your case a field is a sequence of numbers. `NF` contains the number of fields, which is the value that you want.